# Fitting a Copula to Two Stochastically Dependent Variables in R

Tags: r, copula

I have two sets of observed data, and I would like to model their joint distribution using a copula in R. I have transformed each set into a uniform distribution using their CDFs, and so now I have two series of dependent, uniformly distributed random variables.

How can I model their joint behavior using a copula? I have begun playing around with R's forecast package, but I can't seem to get started. I would like to fit the best copula to my data (Gaussian, Clayton, Gumbel, etc).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data, it's hard to give concrete examples, but have you looked into the `copula` [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/copula/index.html) for `R`? It has functionality (i.e. `fitCopula`) to fit various kinds of copulæ (Archimedean, elliptical, etc.).